# Is there anything that would make a static bool thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I recently came across some code that was working fine where a `static bool` was shared between multiple threads (single writer, multiple receivers) although there was no synchronization.

Something like that (simplified):

```
//header A
struct A {
   static bool f;
   static bool isF() { return f; }
};

//Source A
bool A::f = false;

void threadWriter(){
    /* Do something */
    A::f = true;
}

// Source B
void threadReader(){
   while (!A::isF()) { /* Do something */}
}
```

For me, this kind of code has a race condition in that even though operations on bool are atomic (on most CPUs), we have no guarantee that the write from the writer thread will be visible to the reader threads. But some people told me that the fact that f is `static` would help.

So, is there anything in C++11 that would make this code safe? Or anything related to static that would make this code work?

Comment: No, this code causes UB.

Comment: std::atomic<bool>? Also, even if your  bool was atomic, calling isF() to read it probably isn't.

Comment: This is an old-school attitude and may not be accurate, but I've lived with the belief that if it needs to be thread-safe, it needs a mutex. I'll be watching to see if someone posts a better answer.

Comment: The C++ standard does not guarantee that operations on `bool` are atomic. If you want atomic operations use `std::atomic<bool>`. The implementation will manage the complexities of atomicity, which go beyond the first-level issue of whether a store operation can be torn.

Comment: @JosephLarson -- `std::atomic<T>` provides thread-safe operations on a single object. If that's sufficient, there's no need for a mutex, and the atomic operations may well be faster.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not sure what AlexG's comment about the isF() function implies then, or maybe he's mistaken.

Comment: And it can go a step beyond atomicity of access. Without extra guards like `std::atomic` the compiler is often within it's rights to say "No one changes the value in this loop, so I'll just optimize this test out and loop forever."

Comment: An `atomic<bool>` is not sufficient for this application, at least not the way it is used. You would need to compare-exchange atomically, otherwise it does not protect against simultaneous writes. The flag could be `false` in the condition for multiple threads before any of them set it to `true`. The flag must atomically be set to `true` just as it is measured to be `false` or you still have a race condition.

Comment: @JosephLarson -- it's not clear from the code what the actual use is intended to be. It's not so much the function `ifF()` as how it's used.

Comment: There are two separate issues here. The title asks whether there's a way to make `bool` thread safe, and the answer is `std::atomic<bool>`. There's an additional implied question of how to make the code in the question thread safe, and that's more complicated, in part because the code has been greatly simplified in order to ask the title question.

Comment: actually I dont quite understand the question. Is it "This code smells, but it works. Why?" or is it "This code smells, how to fix it?"

Comment: I think now I get it. Question is "Is the bool thread-safe in this code because it is `static`?", right? Answer is No

Comment: The comments on [A: Lock free synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104017) appear relevant.

Comment: Yes, the question was whether static had anything to do on why this code is working. I know how to fix it (std:.atomic<bool>). Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hardware may be able to atomically operate on a `bool`. However, that does not make this code safe. As far as C++ is concerned, you are writing and reading the `bool` in different threads without synchronisation, which is undefined.

Making the `bool` static does not change that.

To access the `bool` in a thread-safe way you can use a `std::atomic<bool>`. Whether the `atomic` uses a mutex or other locking is up to the implementation.

Though, also a `std::atomic<bool>` is not sufficient to synchronize the `threadReader()` and `threadWriter()` in case each `/*Do something */` is accessing the same shared data.

---

> But some people told me that the fact that f is static would help.

Frankly, this sounds like cargo-cult. I can imagine that this was confused with the fact that initialization of static local variables is thread safe. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables):

> If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local
> variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once (similar
> behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with std::call_once).
>
> Note: usual implementations of this feature use variants of the
> double-checked locking pattern, which reduces runtime overhead for
> already-initialized local statics to a single non-atomic boolean
> comparison.

Look for Meyers singleton to see an example of that. Though, this is merely about initialization. For example here:

```
 int& foo() {
     static int x = 42;
     return x;
 }
```

Two threads can call this function concurrently and `x` will be initialized exactly once. This has no impact on thread-safety of `x` itself. If two threads call `foo` and one writes and another reads `x` there is a data race. However, this is about initialization of static local variables and has nothing to do with your example. I don't know what they meant when they told you `static` would "help".

Comment: This is all correct. But even with `std::atomic<bool>` the code contains other errors. Using an `std::atomic<bool>` does not adequately protect against race conditions between `threadWriter` and `threadReader`. For one, `threadWriter` needs to somehow wait that there is no active `threadReader`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux isnt using `store` and `load` enough synchronization? Sorry, I am not sure if I understand the code completely (and your comment)

Comment: The key here is that "atomically" in "hardware may be able to atomically operate on a `bool`" is not the same as "atomically" in `std::atomic<bool>` supports operating atomically on a `bool` object. `std::atomic` manages potential data races from the perspective of the C++ language, and, properly used, ensures that there are no data races.

Comment: @PeteBecker thats bascially what I wanted to say, just better phrased ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is enough to avoid the UB from accessing the flag. But the scheme used in the question does not synchronize the data manipulated by `threadWriter` and `threadReader` (assuming they touch the same data). If a thread calls `threadWriter` while another is running `threadReader` then there is nothing preventing a race on that shared data.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux if you refer to shared data not shown in OPs code, then I understand what you mean.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, I'm referring to the hypothetical data these member functions would manipulate, but which was not shown in the question.

Comment: To clarify @FrançoisAndrieux you're approaching from a safe transaction point of view rather than merely safe checking of the bool after which `/* Do Something */'` must be safe to execute unsynchronized, yes?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @463035818_is_not_a_number! Regarding the rest of the code, let's assume that it's all local. And I am not looking into a solution that would make it thread-safe. Just looking at whether this kind of code is supposed to be working (it's not!).